# Multiple instances of Firefox over X11

Tags: x11, firefox

I have a jump server that I use to log into to access the other application server over a VPN. However this jump server is used by many people.

so if one persons open Firefox to be forwarded over x11 another person cannot open Firefox. It gives the bellow error.

[image: The error it gives when I run 'firefox &']

so basically only one instance

```
linux-fs:~/.vnc # ps aux | grep firefox
root      8979  0.5  0.7 700000 118212 pts/1   Sl   17:56   0:02 firefox -height 800 -width 740
root     11421  0.0  0.0   4408   772 pts/2    S+   18:05   0:00 grep firefox
```

Is there any way more can be configured ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Firefox user is associated with a profile. This profile basically contains all the preferences, history, bookmarks etc. When Firefox starts, it puts a lock on the profile. This ensures that no other Firefox process uses this profile.

But, this doesn't mean that there can be only one instance of Firefox. It just means there can be only one instance of Firefox *per profile*. Since the jump server is used by different people, you can ask each of them to create a different profile and use their own profile.

But this is a huge inconvenience. Every time someone starts Firefox, a window appears asking what profile to use.

This is a weak solution because there is no one to enforce if someone is using their profile or not. So, other solution would be that if you find someone using Firefox, open Firefox profile manager with

```
firefox -no-remote -ProfileManager
```

and create a new profile. Then start Firefox using this profile. You can delete this profile when you are done with it.

Comment: I suppose we can use that :)

Comment: I've posted another question (with an answer) which maybe useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626984/cannot-open-multiple-instances-of-firefox-with-xdg-open-or-kde-open5-in-opensuse