# Why do graphics programs need a window to be assigned to?

Tags: linux, x11, gui, graphics

My question is better explained as a scenario. Imagine you have your desktop running some form of Linux (I am running arch). Now let's also add in that you have a VNC server running on your machine, giving you a virtual desktop.

I open Firefox on my desktop, and then log into my vnc to work on something. If I have to google something, I will open Firefox and receive the error that a session is already running, so now I have to close out the previous running session of Firefox and then re open it in my vnc. If I forget it's running in my vnc, I have to do the same thing to open it on my desktop.

I am aware there are ways to fix this specific issue, but it is only an example. Why does (in this example) Firefox need to be assigned to only 1 window?

Why can't Firefox be created and not be assigned to any particular window, then when I want it on a particular desktop, it just loads it there instead of having to close and restart it, or start another instance? I suppose a better way to phrase this is: why don't graphics processes run on their own server and then are handed/moved to any requesting desktops?

Comment: Is this the multiple instances of Firefox problem - [answered here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211563/multiple-instances-of-firefox-over-x11)?

Comment: I stated in the question that the Firefox thing is simply an example to explain my question.

Answer (score 1):

Programs that are able to connect to more than one X11 server at a time are very, very rare. Mostly they are specialized applications that are meant to spy on one X11 session and display the results on the other, or things like that. General applications virtually never support this. I'm not sure, but I guess that many of the X11 client libraries contain global variables and other various bits related to the assumption that there will only ever be one X11 connection in each process.

This is usually not a problem because if you want an application to display on two different displays, you just run two copies of it. The trouble is that Firefox doesn't support having two copies of itself run at the same time on the same user account (regardless of whether they are on the same display or not).

Comment: I suppose my question more revolves around the "why". I'm well aware that X11 doesn't support this and most applications don't either. My question is, why was X11 designed like that

Comment: as @celada said, this is not an X issue, this is an application issue.  Some X apps can run multiple instances, some can not.  Some have one instance controlling multiple windows, some run one instance per window.  It's entirely application-specific.   BTW, firefox can run multiple simultaneous instances for the same user, but each one has to have its own profile.

Comment: @T-he-game the "why" question is a history question. I can't really answer except to say the original X11 code was written more than 30-ish years ago and it was probably more bare-bones than anything you'd expect now. So was the hardware from that time...

Comment: Fair enough. I have heard that a handful of OS's are moving to wayland over the next year (Ubuntu, and I believe you can setup arch to run wayland as well for the compositor). Will this be the case for that as well?
and again, Firefox is just one example. Im more questioning the reasoning behind an application being bound to a particular window , instead of being generated and controlled in a  separate area and handed to whatever window is requesting it. I am not sure how exactly to phrase my question, but that is the best way.

Comment: @T-he-game I haven't followed the Wayland story but if I had to guess I think a huge class of applications will be accessing it either using a X11 compatibility layer of some kind or else using toolkit libraries like Gtk and QT which were conceived from the ground up on a model that was built on top of X11, so I'm expecting no change.